# Why does compiler complain that f() is not visible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
typename enable_if<(N > 1), void>::type f(){
    cout << N - 1 << ' ';
    f<N - 1>();
}
template <size_t N>
typename enable_if<N == 1, void> ::type f() {
    cout << 1;
}
int main() {
    f<4>();
}
```

Compiler complains at line 8:

```
f< N - 1 >();
```

> Call to function `f` that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by `ADL`.

Comment: A bit unfortunate that the compiler doesn't show (or you omitted it from this post) that N==2 when this occurs. Also, this problem is usually solved by template specialization (`template<> void f<1>() { }`.

Comment: Can you include the compiler version, and the *entire* error message generated?

Comment: it was compiled by Xcode and i have already posted the entire error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that the function is defined below the function call.

You have two possible approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
typename enable_if<N == 1, void> ::type f() {
    cout << 1;
}

template <size_t N>
typename enable_if<(N > 1), void>::type f(){
    cout << N - 1 << ' ';
    f<N - 1>();
}

int main() {
    f<4>();
}
```

**Approach 2:**

You can **forward declare** the prototype for the `N==1` version function.

Answer (score 10):

Reverse the order of your function definitions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
typename enable_if<N == 1, void> ::type f() {
    cout << 1;
}
template <size_t N>
typename enable_if<(N > 1), void>::type f(){
    cout << N - 1 << ' ';
    f<N - 1>();
}
int main() {
    f<4>();
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
3 2 1 1
```

Comment: ...or forward declare the N==1 version.